# Is AWS Glue Scalable?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have covered all the required information while I'm using glue, please let me know if you need more information.

Here is my scenario:

> aws s3 ls s3://bucuketname/ --recursive  --profile production | grep
>   Auto | wc -l

```
2487
```

There are no more than 2487 s3 interested objects for transformation.

> aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --output json --query
>   "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"  --profile production |
>   awk 'NR!=2 {print $0;next} NR==2 {print $0/1024/1024/1024" GB"}'

```
[
344.768 GB
    3829
]
```

Each s3 object is **not more than 100MB size** and it is a **compressed json**.

3829 is the total number of objects, but I'm interested in only 2487 objects for processing.

**Scala Code:**

```
val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)
val auto01: DynamicFrame = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = "jsondb", tableName = "01").getDynamicFrame()
auto01.printSchema()
```

Trying to get the schema,

```
18/06/09 18:31:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 32, ip-172-31-16-40.ec2.internal, executor 9): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.7 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
18/06/09 18:31:44 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.7 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
..
..
..

18/06/09 18:34:13 WARN ExecutorAllocationManager: Attempted to mark unknown executor 12 idle
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 44, ip-172-31-16-40.ec2.internal, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 6.0 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1026)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1008)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.glue.util.SchemaUtils$.fromRDD(SchemaUtils.scala:57)
  at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.recomputeSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:235)
  at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.schema(DynamicFrame.scala:223)
  at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.printSchema(DynamicFrame.scala:244)
  ... 48 elided
```

Anything am I missing here to consider using glue?

Comment: If you are voting to close, please leave a comment on what is wrong with the question, so that it will be helpful to edit the question based on the needs.